# Insert Duplicate Row Data between 2 Dates Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, date-range, medical

I'm trying to find a method of duplicating all of the data in a row for every day between  dates. Start date and end date.

This is the dataset:

```
Name            Medication  Start       End         Dose
James Jameson   Depakote    2013-07-01  2015-04-13  1500
James Jameson   Depakote    2015-04-14  2015-04-22  1750
James Jameson   Depakote    2015-04-23  2015-06-30  2000
James Jameson   Naltrexone  2013-07-01  2015-06-30  100
James Jameson   Trazodone   2013-07-01  2015-06-30  300
James Jameson   Xanex       2013-07-01  2014-02-01  0
James Jameson   Xanex       2014-02-02  2015-06-30  1
James Jameson   Zoloft      2014-03-21  2015-06-30  100
James Jameson   Zoloft      2014-07-01  2014-03-20  50
```

What I would like to do is repeat the row, incrementing the date, every day between the start and end values. I feel I can do this with some combination of date range and append but I can't find a solution for the entire row.

Example outcome:

```
Name            Medication  Start       End         Dose
James Jameson   Depakote    2013-07-01  2015-04-13  1500
James Jameson   Depakote    2013-07-02  2015-04-13  1500
James Jameson   Depakote    2013-07-03  2015-04-13  1500
James Jameson   Depakote    2013-07-x   2015-04-13  1500
.
.
.
James Jameson   Depakote    2015-04-13  2015-04-13  1500
James Jameson   Depakote    2015-04-14  2015-04-22  1750
James Jameson   Depakote    2015-04-15  2015-04-22  1750
James Jameson   Depakote    2015-04-16  2015-04-22  1750
James Jameson   Depakote    2015-04-x   2015-04-22  1750
.
.
.
James Jameson   Depakote    2015-04-22  2015-04-22  1750
James Jameson   Depakote    2015-04-23  2015-06-30  2000
James Jameson   Naltrexone  2013-07-01  2015-06-30  100
James Jameson   Trazodone   2013-07-01  2015-06-30  300
James Jameson   Xanex       2013-07-01  2014-02-01  0
James Jameson   Xanex       2014-02-02  2015-06-30  1
James Jameson   Zoloft      2014-03-21  2015-06-30  100
James Jameson   Zoloft      2014-07-01  2014-03-20  50
```

So ultimately it will create a new duplicate row for every day between the start date and end date in the original dataframe.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking for. Can you [edit] to include a sample of your expected output and code for what you've tried so far?

Comment: Done, I hope this is a little clearer. Thanks for taking the time to look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `reindex` with `groupby`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'James Jameson', 1: 'James Jameson', 2: 'James Jameson', 3: 'James Jameson', 4: 'James Jameson'}, 'Medication': {0: 'Depakote', 1: 'Depakote', 2: 'Depakote', 3: 'Naltrexone', 4: 'Trazodone'}, 'Start': {0: '2013-07-01', 1: '2015-04-14', 2: '2015-04-23', 3: '2013-07-01', 4: '2013-07-01'}, 'End': {0: '2015-04-13', 1: '2015-04-22', 2: '2015-06-30', 3: '2015-06-30', 4: '2015-06-30'}, 'Dose': {0: 1500, 1: 1750, 2: 2000, 3: 100, 4: 300}})
df[['Start','End']] = df[['Start','End']].apply(pd.to_datetime)


df2 = pd.concat([g.set_index('Start').reindex(pd.date_range(g['Start'].min(), g['End'].max(), freq='d'), method='ffill').reset_index().rename({'index':'Start'}, axis=1)
                 for _, g in df.groupby(['Name','Medication','Dose'])],
                axis=0)
```

A bit more detail in response to the question below -- the list comprehension is effectively just this `for` loop put onto one line. There is a lot of text, but it only looks as complex as it does because it isn't storing values in variables -- though doing so may make what's happening a bit clearer. *Viz.*:

```
# undoing the list comprehension...
sub_dfs = []
for group_value, group_df in df.groupby(['Name','Medication','Dose']):
    print(group_value)
    # if not using the group_value for anything, you can just put '_' 
    # to unpack the .groupby() tuple but not bother naming it
    
    # construct date range
    group_start_date = group_df['Start'].min()
    group_end_date = group_df['End'].max()
    group_date_range = pd.date_range(group_start_date, group_end_date, freq='d')
    
    new_group_df = group_df.set_index('Start').reindex(group_date_range, method='ffill').reset_index().rename({'index':'Start'}, axis=1)
    sub_dfs.append(new_group_df)
    
df2b = pd.concat(sub_dfs, axis=0)
```

Comment: Cleaner and even more faster solution.

Comment: Thank you both! Both answers are very helpful. @Brendan this solution is great and works perfectly, though I'd like to understand it a little better. Could you give me a high level explanation of what's going on here? Obviously it's a list comprehension though it's the most complex I've ever seen.

Comment: For example what is the '_' character in the loop iterating?

Comment: @JohnConor See edits above; hopefully those answer your questions. The line assigning `new_group_df` is still long, but it's just setting an index, reindexing, then resetting and renaming the index variable.

Comment: '_' character is used in python when you want to omit the variable, in this case this groupby object when you iterate through it is consisted of two variables, first one which he omitted is a tuple of values by which the dataframe was grouped by, second one ('g') is the actual row which is the result of group by operation.

Edit: Again I'm slow :D, great explanation @Brendan

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want. Firstly utilize pd.to_datetime to convert to datetime objects and create an empty list to store the values afterward.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("example_data.csv")

df["Start"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Start"])
df["End"]=pd.to_datetime(df["End"])
row_list = []
```

Then iterate through range of dates for each row using nested for in between start and end using pd.date_range

```
for row in df.index:
    for date in pd.date_range(start=df["Start"][row], end=df["End"][row]):
        temp_dict = {"Name": df.Name[row], "Medication": df.Medication[row], "Start" : date,
            "End" : df.End[row], "Dose" : df.Dose[row]}
        row_list.append(temp_dict)
```

Lastly create a new dataframe using the afore created and populated list

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(row_list)
```

Note that this is much faster thand utilizing pd.append

Comment: Solution is valid, but @Brendan is even better, use that one